Getting incorrect errors on laravel docker container
I've recently been learning docker and trying to convert an existing web app into a container. However, I've been getting a consistent error for days which I still haven't resolved. The project works totally fine on local and on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (via CodePipeline). It's just on docker that it's plagued with this error which does not even make sense.
If you can see the image below, the error is related to line 51 (previously line 50); so I added a dd on line 44 but the error references line 50 and does not even trigger the dd (line 44) and then still shows the error on line 51 (previously line 50 before I added dd). I've been scratching my head over this for a few days now when I work on it on my free time. It just doesn't make sense to me.

I would like to note that composer install, npm install, and npm run build are all successful. The public, node_modules, and vendor folders are all added to dockerignore and gitignore. So they are all generated/compiled during runtime before being served by fpm and nginx. None of these files are copied to the container from my local or from repository. (AND) I've also tried adding them to the repository (vendor, and public folder after npm run build), but I still get this same error.
docker-compose.yml
services:
server:
    container_name: server
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: xxxx/xxmy-private-repoxx
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
        - /var/www
    ports:
        - "11001:9000"

Dockerfile
FROM php:8.1-fpm as stage-php

# set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# install dependencies
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y curl unzip libsodium-dev libpq-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libonig-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev libicu-dev libzip-dev libxslt-dev software-properties-common nginx npm

# install php extensions and cleanup
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd soap sodium imap intl mysqli xsl pdo pdo_mysql bcmath curl opcache mbstring zip \
    && apt autoremove -y \
    && apt clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# set default user and group
RUN usermod --uid 1000 www-data \
    && groupmod --gid 1000 www-data

# composer and install
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www
COPY --from=composer:2.7.2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# transfer custom configs
COPY ./docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY ./docker/php/zz-docker.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx/fastcgi_params /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./docker/php/entrypoint.sh /app-container-entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /app-container-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app-container-entrypoint.sh"]

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

#if [ ! -f "vendor/autoload.php" ]; then
composer install --no-progress --no-interaction
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/vendor

npm install
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/node_modules

npm run build
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/public
#fi


php-fpm -D
nginx -g "daemon off;"

Hoping someone can point me to the right direction on fixing this. This is the only thing preventing me from making progress to also proceed with converting my other web apps to containers.

Holy. I was able to make it work. I can't believe it's just because of opcache. All I had to do was set opcache.enable=0
php.ini
[opcache]
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=512
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=64
opcache.max_accelerated_files=50000
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=15
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.save_comments=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=1

I'm not really too familiar with opcache configs, and I only copied this somewhere and slightly increased some values (memory consumption and interned_strings_buffer); it was working fine before. I even noticed some slight reduction in loading times (120-140ms to 20-60ms).
I hope someone can explain this if there's anyone familiar with this.
